# How do you produce stacked output from PROC SUMMARY or PROC MEANS?

Tags: sas

Right now when I run a proc summary, the output dataset looks as follows:

```
VAR1 Label Mean VAR2 Label Mean
```

but I want the following format:

```
VAR1 Label Mean 
VAR2 Label Mean
```

How do I do this from my proc summary statement:

```
proc summarydata = full MEAN STD MEDIAN MIN MAX MEDIAN Q1 Q3 P95 P90 P5 print;
var X;
run;
```

Comment: I edited the title some to make it more useful for searching.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SAS 9.3 or newer, and are using `ODS OUTPUT`, you can do this with the `STACKODSOUTPUT` option.

```
ods output summary=test ;
proc summary data=sashelp.class print mean p5 p95 stackodsoutput;
class sex;
var height weight;
run;
ods output close;
```

If you are doing it via the `output` statement in the PROC, or have SAS 9.2 or earlier, you will have to postprocess the data to transpose it.  If you used `/AUTONAME`, you can do so fairly easily.

```
proc summary data=sashelp.class print mean p5 p95 stackodsoutput;
class sex;
var height weight;
output out=test mean= p5= p95= /autoname;
run;

data test2;
set test;
array vars height: weight:;
do _t = 1 to dim(vars);
  varname = scan(vname(vars[_t]),1,'_'); *this would be more complex if you have _ in your variable names;
  statistic = scan(vname(vars[_t]),-1,'_'); *this would be okay, though;
  value = vars[_t];
  output;
end;
keep sex varname statistic value;
run;

proc transpose data=test2 out=test3(drop=_name_);
by sex varname;
id statistic;
var value;
run;
```

Comment: Additionally, [this paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/059-31.pdf) on the `%bettermeans` macro might be interesting, both for the actual macro to use, and to see the approaches taken by the folks developing it.

Comment: What happens if the variables are in a macro variable called &vars.?

Comment: @lord12 That's not particularly relevant to the first part of the question; they resolve to text and are handled as if they weren't.  If you're asking for how to do the second method, the only challenge is constructing the array specification, which either requires making a new macro variable with colons added, or requires differently structuring your array specification - perhaps simply using `_NUMERIC_` and explicitly avoiding the couple of variables that would qualify that are unwanted (`_TYPE_` and `_FREQ_` in particular).